# Open and closing ODBC connections causing crashes

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt

I wrote a program that used a SQLite database and it worked correctly. Now I'm trying to make it work with SQL Server. The application crashes on startup and I have worked out that it's to do with the way I am opening and closing database connections. I'm really unsure if I need to open the connection only once or if should I open and close it each time I run a query? Also is it advised to delete the pointer to the query after it executes? Removing the conn.connOpen and conn.connClose sections makes the program run, but its unstable.

Any advice on how to handle connections (since I have a lot of buttons that execute different queries) is greatly appreciated.

My connection string is stored in a header (mainwindow)

```
// mainwindows.h 

public:
QSqlDatabase mydb;
void connClose()
{
    connected = false;
    mydb.close();
    mydb.QSqlDatabase();
    mydb.removeDatabase(QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection);
}

bool connOpen()
{
    if( !connected )
    {
        mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC"); //uses dsn, connects fine. 
        mydb.setDatabaseName("Test");
        if(!mydb.open())
        {                    
            qDebug() << mydb.lastError().text();
            connected = false;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug()<<"Connected";
            connected = true;
        }
    }
    return connected;
}

private:
static bool connected;
```

Here is an example of how I'm calling queries in my .cpp files;

```
Financelog::Financelog(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Financelog)
{    
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowFlags( windowFlags() | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint | 
                    Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint | Qt::WindowMinMaxButtonsHint );

    MainWindow conn; // call the connection string
    if(!conn.connOpen())
        ui->label_sec_status->setText("<font color='red'>Failed to Open Database</font>"); 
    else
        ui->label_sec_status->setText("<font color='green'>Connected</font>");

    QSqlQueryModel * modal=new QSqlQueryModel();

    conn.connOpen(); // ---- **DO I NEED THIS? REMOVING STOPS CRASHES.** 

    QSqlQuery* qry=new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);

    qry->prepare("select DEAL_DATE, DEAL_NUMB, CCICOMM, CCIPREM, INCOME from LOG");     
    qry->exec();
    modal->setQuery(*qry);
    ui->tableView->setModel(modal); 
    ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
    ui->tableView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    ui->tableView->setStyleSheet("alternate-background-color: #009900; background-color: #006600;");

    //delete qry;  **DO I NEED THIS TO RELEASE MEMORY?**

    conn.connClose(); // **DO I NEED THIS?** 

    qDebug() << (modal->rowCount());
}
```

Comment: In sqlite there is no user or password but in other databases if there are any, you have to pass these parameters: `QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase ("QODBC");
     db.setHostName ("ip of your database");
     db.setDatabaseName ("database name");
     db.setUserName ("your user");
     db.setPassword ("your password");
     bool ok = db.open ();`

Comment: Thanks but I can connect to the database fine. I'm having crashes due to opening and closing the connection when preparing and executing the query. Removing the conn.connOpen and conn.connClose fixes the crashes but I have no idea why. Appears to be specific to the sql server driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should only open the connection once, and keep it open while using it. **Not** open and close for every query.

   - If you have long phases of nothing between 2 queries, you can use a `QTimer` to close the connection after beeing unused for a "long" time (e.g. 5 min). Do so if you see the connection timing out. But by default, not needed.
2. `QSqlQuery`, just like `QSqlDatabase` should be used as "value class", not as a pointer (See [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#details)). Instead of creating one with `new`, create it on the stack. Queries are copyable.

Code sample:

```
//only once, i.e. in your windows constructor
conn.connOpen();

//set up the model
QSqlQueryModel * modal=new QSqlQueryModel();

QSqlQuery qry(conn.mydb);

qry.prepare("...");     
qry.exec();
modal->setQuery(qry);
//...

// do not delete the query or close the database connection!

qDebug() << (modal->rowCount());
```

You can close the connection in the destructor **after** the model has been destroyed:

```
model->deleteLater();
conn.connClose();
```

Comment: Thanks Felix, just to understand better, I have put my connection string in the mainwindow.h and the connection is open as long as the program is. I only close the connection when the program quits. Is this ok or should i open and close the connection in the constructor / destructor of each window the program uses?

Comment: Thats totally fine - as long as the mainwindow lives for the whole livespan of your application. If not, move the code to your main

Comment: Thanks again Felix, i'm facing a challenge where there is a very long time between queries in my program. After a while (30 - 40 min) the qtableview will simply go blank. I'm still trying to work out if this is because of a SQL server timeout, connection drop or if it's a video card issue. Would a network fault cause the qtableview to suddenly empty? I only ask since the documentation states that "the connection must remain open while the query exists; otherwise, the behavior of QSqlQuery is undefined." In which case should I open and close the connection or refresh the query using a timer?

Comment: You can simply use a `QTimer` to send dummy queries like `SELECT 1 FROM SomeTable WHERE 0` every 10 minutes or so